# Suggest another term for "patch"

Tags: synonyms

Which other term/terms (literary preferably) can we use instead of "patch" in this sentence?
There were patches of clouds in the sky.
I have only found streak so far.

Comment: blotches, marks, spots, smudges, speckles, smears, stains, streaks, blemishes

Comment: @Bahman Please share your existing research so that other members of the community don't waste time researching and suggesting words you have already found and rejected. ELU is not a general research tool.

Comment: @Christopher Necessary. OP didn't. (Though it could be argued they should: reading the site rules gives a clear explanation.)

Comment: In my biz we often called them "quick fixes". ;)

Comment: A "scattering" of clouds, although this is probably less common than the options supplied by @Christopher.

Answer (score 2):

[chevrons](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chevron) ("a shape, pattern, or object in the form of a V or an upside-down V")
"[white] chevrons across the [aquamarine] sky" or "[layered] chevron clouds atop the [blue] sky"

or [puffs](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/puff) ("a movement of gas, smoke, or air that can be seen or felt")

or wisps ("a thin streak of smoke, mist, etc.") (from same website as puffs; I can only post 2 links)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.This post would be improved by explaining *why* you suggest these terms, for example, by providing a dictionary definition or examples in the wild. I encourage you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Clumps, tufts, or billows may do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

"Shreds of clouds" maybe a good option.

Comment: You could improve this answer by expanding on what you have written: Example; you could include a definition of *"shreds"* to show how your answer fits the OP's question.